# JEST Test Result Varies by User

Tags: lwc-jest

We have a JEST test for an LWC in our managed package that runs without error for one user in VS Code, but runs with two errors for another user.

**The test and underlying code are identical for both users. Both users invoke the test from the terminal in VS Code**

Any thoughts on where to look for differences?

Thanks.

Comment: All other tests run without error for both users.

Comment: what's the error? Are both users using the same source code if they're invoking it in their local - even if they're on the same branch, have they both pulled the latest updates? Also, as a FYI, you can [edit] your own post instead of having to add comments if you have more information to share.

Comment: Yes they are running the exact same code and the same version of all VS Code plugins.  The error is a null object reference when accessing elements on the page.  For two of us this command returns no elements but for one person it returns several elements: let comboBoxes = element.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('lightning-combobox');

Comment: It's a hard question to answer I know but we don't even know where to start to look.  Exact same code, exact same VS Code environment, different test results...

Comment: do you mind sharing the relevant parts of the LWC and the test? I presume the LWC runs fine in a sandbox across users?